# Multi-machine Vagrant project not provisioning as per docs

Tags: vagrant, homestead, vagrant-provision

I’ve trying to set up a multi-machine Vagrant project. According to the docs (https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/multi-machine/), provisioning is “outside in”, meaning any top-level provisioning scripts are executed before provisioning scripts in individual machine blocks.

The project contains a Laravel project, and a Symfony project. My `Vagrantfile` looks like this:

```ruby
require "json"
require "yaml"

confDir = $confDir ||= File.expand_path("vendor/laravel/homestead", File.dirname(__FILE__))

homesteadYamlPath = "web/Homestead.yaml"
homesteadJsonPath = "web/Homestead.json"
afterScriptPath = "web/after.sh"
aliasesPath = "web/aliases"

require File.expand_path(confDir + "/scripts/homestead.rb")

Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|
  config.vm.provision "shell", path: "init.sh"

  config.vm.define "web" do |web|
    web.ssh.forward_x11 = true

    if File.exists? aliasesPath then
      web.vm.provision "file", source: aliasesPath, destination: "~/.bash_aliases"
    end

    if File.exists? homesteadYamlPath then
      Homestead.configure(web, YAML::load(File.read(homesteadYamlPath)))
    elsif File.exists? homesteadJsonPath then
      Homestead.configure(web, JSON.parse(File.read(homesteadJsonPath)))
    end

    if File.exists? afterScriptPath then
      web.vm.provision "shell", path: afterScriptPath
    end
  end

  config.vm.define "api" do |api|
    api.vm.box = "ubuntu/trusty64"

    api.vm.provider :virtualbox do |vb|
      vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--memory", "2048"]
    end

    api.vm.network "private_network", ip: "10.1.1.34"
    api.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 80, host: 8001
    api.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 3306, host: 33061
    api.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 9200, host: 9201

    api.vm.synced_folder "api", "/var/www/api"

    api.vm.provision "shell", path: "api/provision.sh"
  end
end
```

I have a block (`web`) for the Laravel project, where I’ve copied the contents of the Homestead-based `Vagrantfile`, and an `api` block that uses the “standard” Vagrant configuration.

To bootstrap the projects, I created a simple shell script (**init.sh**) that simply clones the Git repositories into git-ignored directories. Given the documentation says configuration works outside-in, I’d therefore expect that script to run, and then the machine-specific blocks, but this doesn’t seem to be happening. Instead, on `vagrant up`, I receive the following error:

> There are errors in the configuration of this machine. Please fix the following errors and try again:
>
> vm:
>   * A box must be specified.

It seems it’s still trying to provision the individual machines, before running the shell script. I know the shell script isn’t getting called as I added an `echo` statement to it. Instead, the terminal just outputs the following:

> Bringing machine 'web' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
>   Bringing machine 'api' up with 'virtualbox' provider...

So how can I get Vagrant to run my shell script first? I think it’s failing because the `web` group is checking if my **web/Homestead.yaml** file exists and if so, use the values in there for configuring (including the box name), but as my shell script hasn’t been ran and hasn’t cloned the repository that file does not exist, so there is no `box` specified, which Vagrant complains about.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you do not define a `box` for the `web` machine. You need to either define the box in the outer space like

```
config.vm.box = "ubuntu/trusty64"
```

if you plan to use the same box/OS for both machines or define in the `web` scope

```
web.vm.box = "another box"
```

**EDIT**

Using the `provision` property will run the script in the VM, which is not what you want here, as you want the script to run on your host. (and because it runs in the VM, it needs the VM to be booted first)

Vagrantfile is just a simple ruby script, so you could add your script or even an execution to it (from ruby call), a potential issue I could see is that you cannot guarantee the execution and specially that the execution of your init script will be complete before vagrant does it things on the VM.

A possibility is to use the [vagrant trigger plugin](https://github.com/emyl/vagrant-triggers) and execute your shell script before the `up` event

```
  config.trigger.before :up do
    info "Dumping the database before destroying the VM..."
    run  "init.sh"   
  end
```

Running it this way, vagrant will wait for the script to be executed before it runs its part of the `up` command.

You would need to do some check in your script to make sure it runs only when needed, otherwise, it will run everytime you start the machine (invoking `vagrant up`), e.g. you could make a check on the presence of the yaml file

Comment: As per my question, the values _including the box name_ are in **web/Homestead.yaml**. I need Vagrant to run my **init.sh** script to clone the project that contains this file first.

Comment: It is not because you declare in your yaml file that vagrant will know about it, you still need to declare the value for `config.vm.box` or `web.vm.box` and point to the value from your yaml file

Comment: I think I know what’s in my **Homestead.yaml** file. You may want to take a look at Laravel Homestead, as that’s how it provisions Vagrant.

Comment: the error from vagrant is straight clear `* A box must be specified.` so you don't paste your yaml file but clear vagrant is not able to find from all your config file which box it needs to use so it does not start

Comment: Yes, because my **init.sh** script isn’t running, which _would clone the project that contains the **Homestead.yaml** file Vagrant should use to provision_.

Comment: @MartinBean did I get this right this time ? did trigger plugin help in your case ?